# FitText plugin only resizing first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am working with fitText to separately resize two h1 elements and a p in my website. Only the first element after document load and the first element after window.resize are being resized.

I am getting an error in the console: 
"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'", from line 37 or fitText.js:

```
$(window).on('resize.fittext orientationchange.fittext', resizer);
```

Which I know from experience means that the window object is not available to the plugin when a consecutive fitText() call happens.

See for yourself at http://www.jjplusplus.com 
I am working off of the fitText example example.html from the gitHub; mine matches it almost exactly but breaks on the initial load:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    //this first line runs
    $("#webBeast").fitText(0.65);
    //both consecutive calls to .fitText() throw a console error
    $("#razorsEdge").fitText(0.65);
    $("#l2").fitText();
    ...
}

$( window ).resize(function() {
    //this resizes the razorsEdge element
    $("#razorsEdge").fitText(0.65);
    //these lines do not resize
    //even though #webBeast was the element that initially resized
    $("#webBeast").fitText(0.65);
    $("#l2").fitText();
});
```

feel free to inspect my code directly off of the website, again http://www.jjplusplus.com

Answer (score 1):

What worked was commenting out the line in the plugin :

$(window).on('resize.fittext orientationchange.fittext', resizer);

That was throwing the error.
What strikes me is that this lines' purpose is to call the resizer function when the window is resized... However it isn't necessary in my case because I am listening for the resize event and calling the fitText fn on each element manually.

Interesting? Certainly. Did I truly answer the question? Not entirely. I still wish I knew why it didn't work.